# didSelectRowAtIndexPath + performSegueWithIdentifier + modal segue = Can't add self as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I've searched repeatedly for related answers but didn't find (or probably, didn't understand) anything relevant. Some facts:

1) I'm very, very new at this.
2) I'm using Xcode 5 & targeting an iOS 7 iPad
3) I'm attempting to add 1 feature (yeah, kiss of death) to a large, existing application written by someone I'm not able to contact

The app has a split view controller that links to a navigation controller that links to a table view (& a whole bunch of other views related to the original split view).
If the table item selected by the user has a specific value, I want to open a new view (otherwise let the existing logic handle it).

I created a new view controller with a modal segue from the table view. I added a test to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
if( [[object name] isEqualToString:@"SpecialCase"]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

This worked at least once, until I started trying to pass information to the new view. I've since added:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ScSegue"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    CBPeripheral *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
}
```

I've added the necessary def/decl for setDetailItem() to my new view controller. I don't know if I broke something while I was doing that, but even if I back all of this out, to where I was when I first added the segue call, I still get "Can't add self as subview". Yes, I done Clean in between.

I realize that I'm probably too unknowledgeable to be attempting this, but it's my job to do it. I've spent most of the day searching for clues without success so I'm humbling myself before the snarkfest. Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Hello @GerryO, put break point on your code and do a step by step debugging, and tell me on which line you get the exception.

Comment: Hello & thanks! I should have included that. The error occurs when this line is executed: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScSegue" sender:nil];

Answer (score 3):

For swift:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showItemDetail", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showItemDetail" {
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let detailVC:ItemDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ItemDetailViewController
        detailVC.item = items[indexPath.row] as Item

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:tableView];
    }
```

in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        indexPath = [self.table indexPathForSelectedRow];
        SiteMap *site;
        site = [self.listSite objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Detail *detailController = (Detail*)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailController.string = @"hello";
    }
}
```

this means that your "next view" name is Detail and has a property named string of type NSString

Comment: Thanks for responding, but Xcode isn't happy with this. Sorry to be such a noob but what is a SiteMap? I can't find a reference to this anywhere. Also, where you've used "Detail" I think this should be replaced with the name of my actual detail view controller? Or is this another keyword I'm unable to find explained anywhere (that I've looked so far)? Again, your help is very much appreciated!